# How can i use .where in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have this part of code to get a collection firebase

```
const db = getFirestore(app)
const getCollection = name => collection(db, name)
const collection = getCollection(db, 'chars')
const query = await collection.where('name', '==', value)
```

i am getting error in `.where` is not a function, what is the wrong?

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): collection.where is not a function

Comment: I am confused, your second line is function which accepts `name` (1 param) and calls `collection` function. Then in next line you are calling that function with 2 params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the new modular SDK, where all functions are top-level.

To create a query, do:

```
const query = query(collection, where('name', '==', value))
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [building queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-9_1).

Comment: how can i use the old modular SDK?

Comment: The code in my answer is the equivalent of the last line in your question, but then using the modular SDK. You were mixing the new and the old syntax, which isn't possible within a single Firebase module.